# Outlook iCal meeting invitation description issue

Tags: email, events, outlook, icalendar, rfc5545

I am sending `iCal` `event` invitation using `php`. Everything displays in proper manner and `RVSP` button displayed correctly. But `description` is `cutting down` after `first line`. For example if my description is:

```
The problem occurs when I have multiple lines in the description. 
If it contains the text for example I will only get in my outlook calendar 
description. The part after disappears.
```

The only first line displays like:

```
The problem occurs when I have multiple lines in the description.
```

If someone help me.
I have already wrap the lines but after first line it will not displayed. Here is code snippet.

```
function ical_split($preamble, $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    $value = strip_tags($value);
    $value = preg_replace('/\n+/', ' ', $value);
    $value = preg_replace('/\s{2,}/', ' ', $value);
    $preamble_len = strlen($preamble);
    $lines = array();
    while (strlen($value)>(74-$preamble_len)) {
        $space = (74-$preamble_len);
        $mbcc = $space;
        while ($mbcc) {
            $line = mb_substr($value, 0, $mbcc);
            $oct = strlen($line);
            if ($oct > $space) {
                $mbcc -= $oct-$space;
            }
            else {
                $lines[] = $line;
                $preamble_len = 1; // Still take the tab into account
                $value = mb_substr($value, $mbcc);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!empty($value)) {
        $lines[] = $value;
    }
    return join($lines, "\\n\\t");
}
```

And I called it as follows:

```
$meeting_notes="The problem occurs when I have multiple lines in the description. If it contains the text for example I will only get in my outlook calendar description. The part after disappears."
ical_split('DESCRIPTION:', $meeting_notes)
```

Here the detail of attached ics file.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//Microsoft Corporation//Outlook 11.0 MIMEDIR//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:REQUEST
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20150227T163000Z
DTEND:20150227T173000Z
DTSTAMP:20150211T094306Z
ORGANIZER;CN=Charlene Switzer:MAILTO:email_here
UID:40
ATTENDEE;CUTYPE=INDIVIDUAL;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=NEEDS-ACTION;RSVP=TRUE;CN=name_here;X-NUM-GUESTS=0:MAILTO:email_here
DESCRIPTION:The problem occurs when I have multiple lines in the description. If it contains the text for example I will only get in my outlook calendar description. The part after disappears.
LOCATION:asdf asd
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
TRANSP:OPAQUE
SUMMARY:Meeting
PRIORITY:5
CLASS:PUBLIC
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Eastern
END:VTIMEZONE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: I formatted your question a bit - it looked as if you experimented with the variety of code markup possibilities (Backticks, quotes, code snippets, indents) :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expend on Dmitry's explanation, you need to refer to RFC5545 which specifies the iCalendar format

**[3.1. Content Lines][1]**

> The iCalendar object is organized into individual lines of text,
> called content lines.  Content lines are delimited by a line break,
> which is a CRLF sequence (CR character followed by LF character).

> Lines of text SHOULD NOT be longer than 75 octets, excluding the line
> break.  Long content lines SHOULD be split into a multiple line
> representations using a line "folding" technique.  That is, a long
> line can be split between any two characters by inserting a CRLF
> immediately followed by a single linear white-space character (i.e.,
> SPACE or HTAB).

So back to your question, like Dmitry's suggest you should add a `TAB` or a `SPACE` after your CRLF but also you should make sure your lines aren't longer than 75bytes.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.1

Comment: Can you send me any example using php.?

Comment: I do not code in php, maybe you could share the ical file to help see what is wrong in the ouptu

Comment: I have posted the ics file detail. Please have a look at that.

Comment: could you add the code snippet with the line folding to see what is failing

Comment: i meant the .ics file with the folded line as I do not have a php setup running to test your code

Comment: I have added the ics file data in the question you can test it.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the second lines start with a tab (0x9) - this way the lines will be correctly unwrapped.

Comment: Can you give me some hint in php to find 75 octets and add tab (0x9)?

Comment: Do you already not wrap the lines? If you don't, you must encode the line breaks - replace them with \n.

Comment: Also, if you have specific code questions, post the relevant snippets of your code and indicate clearly what the problem is.

Comment: I have specified the code snippet. Please check it.

Comment: I don't use PHP, so it looks Ok to me... Can you step through your code? What exactly does not work?

Comment: `return join($lines, "\\n\\t");`
 It will added a tab and a new line. It will fold it correctly but when we open the event in calender  and click on view details only first row display.